# Does JavaScript have the equivalent of the ? : operator?

Tags: javascript, operators

Does JavaScript have the equivalent of the `? :` operator that you have in Java?

Ie:

```
String s = (isBlah ? "blah" : "not blah");
```

Comment: Just wondering, didn't you have any chance to just *try* it out?

Comment: @BalusC You know, not everyone knows the name and `? :` does not turn up any Google results.

Comment: @cwallenpoole - You have to know its name in order to try it?

Comment: @cwallenpoole - It's true that it's a difficult search term - but it's not difficult to just try it out in javascript, which is what BalusC actually said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, very close to what you have:

```
variable = (condition) ? true-value : false-value;
```

So for your variables:

```
var s = (isBlah) ? "blah" : "not blah";
```

Mozilla.org Reference Docs:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: It's not just "very close". It's exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 2):

Yup.

```
(condition) ? expr1 : expr2
```

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly the same, except you don't need parentheses in JavaScript.

Comment: do you need the parenthesis in Java?

Comment: They are in the particular example of the OP optional as well. After all, it's **exactly** the same, no exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a ternary operator.  It is in most (all?) C style languages.  Yes, it is in js, as well as Java, C++, PHP, etc.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation

Comment: Nope, it's called the ‘conditional operator’ and it *is* a ternary operator, the only ternary operator JavaScript has. Compare this to unary operator, like unary `+`, unary increment, etc.

Comment: @marcel Touché.  I've only heard it called ternary until now.  That is good to know.